# User getting error while clicking on Open this Task from Outlook 2010/2013

Tags: sharepoint-enterprise, outlook

This is the 2013 Environment and User on receipt of Task in there email when they click on Open this Task on the Outlook 2010/2013(on the OutLook Ribbon) users gets error stating

Outlook cannot open a new form, the form contains schema validation errors.

Please advise.[image]

Note - The user can get to the workflow when he clicks on the task from the body of the email but they are not able to utilize the **Open this task** Tab on the Outlook ribbon.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As given in the error message, the issue is with the Body column of workflow tasks list. For the approval workflow, there would be a tasks list. In the workflow task list, Body column is Enhance Rich multi-line column. Change the setting to Plain text, instead of enhanced rich text.

May be required IISreset.

http://mysharepointkb.blogspot.com/2012/11/cannot-open-sharepoint-2010-approval.html